# Using @Autowired component in custom JSR-303 validator

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, bean-validation

I'm trying to implement a custom validator for my model classes that autowires a custom bean of mine (declared via `@Component`).
In this, I followed the [Spring documentation on that topic](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring). My `AuthenticationFacade` object is implemented according to [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security).

When running my tests, however, the autowired attribute in the `Validator` object is always `null`. Why is that?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**My custom bean**, `AuthenticationFacadeImpl.java`

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFacadeImpl implements AuthenticationFacade {
    boolean hasAnyRole(Collection<String> roles) {
        // checks currently logged in user roles
    }
}
```

**My custom constraint**, `HasAnyRoleConstraint.java`

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = HasAnyRoleConstraintValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface HasAnyRole {
    String[] value();
    String message() default "{HasAnyRole}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**My custom validator**, `HasAnyRoleConstraintValidator.java`

```
@Component
public class HasAnyRoleConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<HasAnyRole, Object> {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    private String[] roles;

    @Override
    public void initialize(HasAnyRole hasAnyRole) {
        this.roles = hasAnyRole.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object target, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return target == null || authenticationFacade.hasAnyRole(Arrays.asList(this.roles));
    }
}
```

**The model class**, `Article.java`

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    // ...
    @HasAnyRole({"EDITOR", "ADMIN"})
    private String title;
    // ...
}
```

**The service object**, `ArticleServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService {
    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'EDITOR')")
    public boolean createArticle(Article article, Errors errors) {
        articleRepository.save(article);
        return true;
    }
```

The `Errors` object that gets fed into the `createArticle` method is intended to come from the Spring controller, which gets fed a model object with the `@Valid` annotation.

**The repository**, `ArticleRepository.java`, uses Spring Data JPA's `JpaRepository`

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for now by ditching Dependency Injection for the Validator class, instead instantiating an instance of `AuthenticationFacadeImpl` in the constructor.
Would still be interesting, though how to combine the use of `@Valid` in the Controllers with custom validators + `@Autowired` attributes in the Model without explicitely calling the Validator in the code...

Answer (score 0):

If your validator is instantiated outside the Spring context, then you can use Spring’s AOP [@Configurable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) magic to register it in context and get autowiring work. All what you need is to annotate `HasAnyRoleConstraintValidator` with `@Configurable` and enable compile time, or load time aspects weaving.